# Single Sign On(LDAP) authentication in moodle does not work properly

Tags: php, apache, authentication, single-sign-on, moodle

This is my first time experience of SSO authentication using LDAP in moodle. I use web server( Apache 2.4) in Window Server 2012 R2.

My LDAP authentication is success without SSO. But if it is authenticated with SSO, it does not work correctly.If I login in with incorrect username and password for the user in LDAP server, show the following error.

## **Unauthorized**

*This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supply the wrong credentials(e.g, bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.*

If I login with correct user name and  password, it redirect to our moodle home page and need to login again. Actually, I need to login our moodle site with SSO authentication directly.

I use mod_authnz_sspi module and here is my config Apache configuration file (httdp.conf).

```
Load Module sspi_auth_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so

<LocationMatch ^/$> 
AuthType SSPI 
AuthName "TECHNO" 
SSPIAuth On 
SSPIAuthoritative On 
SSPIOfferBasic On 
Require valid-user 
</LocationMatch>.
```

Please could you please anyone help me to work the SSO authentication properly?
Many Thanks

Comment: Have you been through the instructions here? https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/NTLM_authentication

Comment: Thank a lot! Now it is working properly. Actually, I need to enable the NTLM/Integrated Authentication on the server.